# Is there a word for the urge to do something creative?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a succinct word for the 'itch' to do something creative? For example having a niggle in your brain where only doing something creative can make it go away?

Comment: Define "be creative". How does an urge to be creative differ from a more general urge to ***do*** something? Does "Learn French" count as a "creative act"? How about "Listen to an opera"? (and would that be any different to "Listen to a radio talk show", or "Watch daytime TV"?).

Comment: Not a real word in the sense you want it to mean: procreative.

Comment: "Insanity" is probably the word you're looking for.

Answer (score 8):

One might also refer to being "stricken by the muse" if there is a specific creative idea demanding that you implement it.

Answer (score 7):

> Inspiration

can do that to you.

Comment: Inspiration might lead to a sudden desire to be creative, but I believe these are two different ideas.

Answer (score 3):

While it isn't a single word, the phrase *creative frenzy* is often heard. By itself, *[frenzy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/frenzy)* means

> A state or period of uncontrolled excitement or wild behavior [*Oxford Dictionary Online*]

Other similar terms are *creative fervor* and *creative fever*.

> *[fervor](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/fever)*: great intensity of feeling or belief; ardour; zeal [*Collins*]
>
> *[fever](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/fever)*: A state of nervous excitement or agitation [*Oxford Dictionary Online*]

The terms could be used by themselves if the context reflected the source of the agitation, as in

> *He was in a frenzy that only a full day of writing could relieve.*

Comment: The best answer so far. IMHO

Comment: A creative frenzy might result from the sensation @Sal is describing, but it doesn't describe the sensation itself.

Comment: "And across the surface of the infinitely adjusted yet somehow effortless mechanics of the feathers, played idle designs of color, no two alike, *designs executed, it seemed, in a controlled rapture*"

Answer (score 2):

The term "creative drive" comes to mind.

"He really possesses a creative drive; he spends 2 hours after work painting every day!"

Alternatively: "She's really creatively driven; even her shoes are homemade."

Answer (score 2):

It's often called a *creative urge*: a sudden and strong compulsion to just create something. I'm not aware of a more succinct term.

Comment: synonymously, a "creative *impulse*".

Comment: @DanBron Would "creative stir" work, too?

Comment: Yes, that's also quite poetic (though rarer, according to Google's Ngrams: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=creative+urge%2C+creative+impulse%2C+creative+stir&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccreative%20urge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccreative%20impulse%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccreative%20stir%3B%2Cc0 )